# C# Integration Testing Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have had some problems with my code is throwing lots of errors during the testing phase (2/10). But I don't understand why. Whereas when I launch my code and access those path everything works fine.

Here is a screenshot of the errors:

[image]

Here is my `System.cs`:

```
using Shard.Shared.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Shard.Shared.Web.API
{
    public class Systems
    {
        public List<SystemSpecification> MySystems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my `SystemController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Shard.Shared.Core;
using Xunit;

namespace Shard.Shared.Web.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SystemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public Systems systemList = new Systems();
        public void CreateUniverse()
        {
            MapGeneratorOptions options = new MapGeneratorOptions
            {
                Seed = "Val Halla"
            };

            MapGenerator map = new MapGenerator(options);
            var array = map.Generate().Systems.ToArray();
            systemList.MySystems = array.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Systems> Get()
        {
            CreateUniverse();
            /*return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new Systems { 
                Sectors = map.Generate(),
                MySystems = array.ToList()
            })*/ yield return systemList;
        }

        [HttpGet("{sectorName}")]
        public IActionResult GetSector(string sectorName)
        {
            CreateUniverse();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sectorName))
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }
            SystemSpecification findSector = systemList.MySystems.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == sectorName);

            if (findSector == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }

            return StatusCode(200, findSector);
        }

        [HttpGet("{sectorName}/planets")]
        public IActionResult GetSectorPlanets(string sectorName)
        {
            CreateUniverse();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sectorName))
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }
            var findSector = systemList.MySystems.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == sectorName);
            if (findSector == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }

            var planets = findSector.Planets;

            if (planets == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }

            Assert.NotNull(findSector);

            return StatusCode(200,planets);
        }

        [HttpGet("{sectorName}/planets/{planetName}")]
        public IActionResult GetSectorPlanets_SpecificPlanet(string sectorName, string planetName)
        {
            CreateUniverse();

            if (sectorName.Trim().Length == 0 || planetName.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }
            else
            {
                /*var findSector = systemList.MySystems.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == sectorName);
                var findPlanetName = findSector.Planets.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == planetName);*/

                foreach (SystemSpecification system in systemList.MySystems)
                {
                    if (system.Name == sectorName)
                    {
                        foreach (PlanetSpecification planet in system.Planets)
                        {
                            if (planet.Name == planetName)
                            {
                                return StatusCode(200, planet);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return StatusCode(404);

                /*if (findSector == null || findPlanetName == null)
                {
                    return StatusCode(404);
                }*/

                //return StatusCode(200, findPlanetName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested all these cases when I launch the program but when it comes to respecting the test cases it's mainly the errors it's displaying that I barely understand. So please I will really appreciate if you guys can help me out.

These are the test cases (`BaseIntegrationTests.SectorTests.cs`):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace Shard.Shared.Web.IntegrationTests
{
    public partial class BaseIntegrationTests<TEntryPoint, TWebApplicationFactory>
    {
        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task CanReadSystems()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();
            Assert.NotEmpty(array);
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task SystemsHaveNames()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();

            Assert.NotNull(array[0]["name"]);
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.String, array[0]["name"].Type);
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task SystemsHavePlanets()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();

            Assert.NotNull(array[0]["planets"]);
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.Array, array[0]["planets"].Type);
            Assert.NotEmpty(array[0]["planets"]);
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task PlanetsHaveNames()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();

            Assert.NotNull(array[0]["planets"][0]["name"]);
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.String, array[0]["planets"][0]["name"].Type);

            var names = array.SelectTokens("$[*].planets[*].name").Select(token => token.Value<string>());
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task PlanetsHaveSizes()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();

            Assert.NotNull(array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size"));
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.Integer, array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size").Type);
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.Integer, array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size").Type);
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "2")]
        public async Task PlanetsDoNotHaveResources()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();
            var allPlanets = array.SelectTokens("[*].planets[*]").Cast<IDictionary<string, JToken>>();
            var allProperties = allPlanets.SelectMany(planet => planet.Keys).Distinct();
            Assert.DoesNotContain("resource", string.Join(",", allProperties));
        }

        public async Task<JToken> GetFirstSystem()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var systemsResponse = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await systemsResponse.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var systems = await systemsResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();
            var system = systems.FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.NotNull(system);

            return system;
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task CanFetchOneSystem()
        {
            var system = await GetFirstSystem();

            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems/" + system["name"].Value<string>());
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            Assert.Equal(system.ToString(), (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>()).ToString());
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task CanFetchPlanetsOfOneSystem()
        {
            var system = await GetFirstSystem();

            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems/" + system["name"].Value<string>() + "/planets");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            Assert.Equal(system["planets"].ToString(), (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>()).ToString());
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        [Trait("version", "1")]
        public async Task CanFetchOnePlanet()
        {
            var system = await GetFirstSystem();
            var planet = system["planets"][0];

            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync(
                "systems/" + system["name"].Value<string>() + "/planets/" + planet["name"].Value<string>());
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            Assert.Equal(planet.ToString(), (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>()).ToString());
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("grading", "true")]
        public async Task NonExistingSectorReturns404()
        {
            using var client = factory.CreateClient();
            using var response = await client.GetAsync("systems");
            await response.AssertSuccessStatusCode();

            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();

            Assert.NotNull(array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size"));
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.Integer, array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size").Type);
            Assert.Equal(JTokenType.Integer, array.SelectToken("[0].planets[0].size").Type);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't really figure out the error messages.

Thanks

Comment: this is not easily replicable for people to actually test and help. please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BagusTesa this is the expected output: [link](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/Duncan-Idaho/shard/1#/)

Comment: You should just `Debug Selected Tests` and you'll find the source of those exceptions just like normal debugging. Click on any failed test cases and you will get more of an error report.

Comment: I suspect in most tests `array[0]` is null and the way you use that is causing all the errors.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your code.Could you share a detailed demo due to you have a partial class?